# RxJs use a subject to trigger a result in the current observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In the code below I have to use setTimeout to get a value from this.parts$(def) because it's chained to an observable that listens to the action event. How can I get around this so I don't need to use a timeout to trigger a result from this.parts$(def)?

```
getParts$ = (def: Def) => {
        setTimeout(() => this.action.next('test'), 1);
        return this.parts$(def);
    };
```

Edit: Action defined as:

```
private action = new Subject<string>();
```

Comment: Could you please say how is `this.action` defined?

Comment: what do you mean by `chained to an observable that listens to the action event`? If you want to react to some ui-action like a click and get values from a subject, you'd probably want to keep a local value of whatever that subject's last emission was for reference, and just .next when said action occurs

Comment: This doesn’t make sense. Please provide a functional and simplified example of your scenario so we can assist you further.

Comment: I can't show how this.parts$ depends on this.action because the dependency is chained through multiple observables and it would take up much code to do so. The important thing is that there is a dependency and that this.parts$ won't yield a result unless this.action.next is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you to do is to subscribe to parts$ before action fire. You can try the below pattern

```
getParts$ = (def: Def) => {
      return new Observable(obs=>{
        const sub=this.parts$(def).subscribe(obs);
        this.action.next('test'), 1);
        return ()=>sub.unsubscribe()
      }
    };
```